# How to pass data from Terraform Kubernetes cluster deployment to Kustomize app deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, argocd, kustomize

We build our cluster with Terraform. We provision EFS storage as part of the deployment, which needs to be referenced by our ArgoCD app deployment. The deployment is a two part process:

1. The infrastructure is deployed via Terraform, configuration is stored in its own repo.
2. We deploy our ArgoCD apps, configuration stored in a separate repo.

The Terraform deployment provisions the Kubernetes cluster and EFS storage and stores the file system ID in a ConfigMap at a known location inside the cluster. I want to use Kustomize to query the ConfigMap and inject the EFS file system ID into a StorageClass manifest that is part of the ArgoCD deployment.

I have a storage app in ArgoCD to manage the storage:

```
|- apps/
   - storage/
     - efs-sc.yaml
     - kustomization.yaml
```

```yaml
# apps/storage/efs-sc.yaml

kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: INJECT-FSID
  directoryPerms: "700"
```

```yaml
# apps/storage/kustomization.yaml

apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - efs-sc.yaml

replacements:
  - source:
      kind: ConfigMap
      name: aws-storage
      namespace: kube-system
      fieldPath: data.efs-file-system-id
    targets:
      - select:
          kind: StorageClass
          name: efs-sc
        fieldPaths:
          - parameters.fileSystemId
```

The output of `kubectl get cm -n kube-system aws-storage -o yaml` is:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  efs-file-system-id: fs-abcdef12345678
immutable: false
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-02-14T11:16:47Z"
  name: aws-storage
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "704"
  uid: 007d0b3f-e7ea-4b24-8eb3-8daa83cdc249
```

When I try to run `kustomize build apps/storage > k.yaml` to test this i get the error `Error: nothing selected by ConfigMap.[noVer].[noGrp]/aws-storage.kube-system:data.efs-file-system-id`.

Am I misunderstanding what `replacements:` can do? Can it read from the live cluster to get data to inject? Or does the data have to be included as a manifest somewhere in the Kustomize deployment? If I have misunderstood this feature, is there another way I can pass data from the Terraform deployment to the ArgoCD deployment?

Edit #1 (added relevant versions)
Kustomize version: v5.3.0
Kubectl:
Client Version: v1.28.3
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.29.0-eks-c417bb3

Comment: I just found a resource stating that Kustomize is client side only, which I suspected.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4718#issuecomment-1217293356

So, how else can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4718#issuecomment-1217293356), Kustomize is client side only. It cannot query any data from server side (cluster). Instead, I rearchitected infrastructure deployment to install the storage class via Terraform. The storage app in ArgoCD deployment is removed and the PVCs still reference the known storage class name.